# Binding a listbox to an Observable Collection of type string in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection

I am trying to create an application that tracks JobItems.  In the application, the user clicks on a "New Job" button to create a JobItem.  A new window (NewJobWindow) then pops up and the user must fill in information about the Job.  A few of the information needed has multiple values.  For instance, you can add multiple (string) Business Units within a job Item.  What I've done is added a listbox for users to add all the business units within it.  What I don't know how to do is bind this listbox of business units so that every time I add an item in it, the Observable Collection BusinessUnits in JobItem gets added the same item when I click the submit button.  I need to know how I would do this using databinding.  I have already searched Google to look for similar answers but could not find any.

**Edit**:

This is what I have in my JobItem Class that I need to get updated every time a user is submitting multiple BusinessUnits in the NewJobWindow:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> BusinessUnit
    {
        get { return businessUnit; }
        set
        {
            if(!BusinessUnit.Equals(value))
            {
                businessUnit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BusinessUnit");
            }
        }

    }
```

This is what the JobWindow looks like in xaml for adding businessunits within the listbox.  I created a ValidatingListBox just so I can validate that the user has inserted an item within the list box.:

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5">Business Unit:</Label>
        <my:ValidatingListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="1" x:Name="businessUnitBox" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="ValidatingListBox_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BusinessUnit}" >
        <my:ValidatingListBox.ValidationListener>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" Path="BusinessUnit" Mode="TwoWay">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <my:ListBoxValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ></my:ListBoxValidationRule>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </my:ValidatingListBox.ValidationListener>
    </my:ValidatingListBox>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binding is very simple:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />
```

where MyCollection is a property of ObservableCollection type. You don't need to add items to ListBox, add them to collection, data binding will do the rest.

Comment: The user needs a UI to add Business Units within the window and that is why I need to add items in a listbox, which would then need to update a collection within the object. How would I reference the collection within the JobItem object?  Please check my edit, maybe you will understand what I'm trying to do better.

Comment: @Erika, I strongly recommending you to read about MVVM pattern. UI is just a presentation. Logic (i. e. "add business unit") must reside with view model, not view (UI).